# Editing an existing answer of a closed-duplicate question vs adding a new answer to the duplicated?

Tags: discussion, support

I posted an answer to some question prior to that question being (rightfully) closed duplicate.
OP went on commenting my answer eventually asking for more explanations / details which are not provided as part of any answer of the duplicated thread.
(The required explanation cannot be a simple comment since it needs going down to the source code)

What would be considered best practice ?

- A/ Edit my answer as part of the closed thread ?
- B/ Post a new answer as part of the duplicated ?
- C/ Edit the (already accepted) answer of the duplicated ?
- D/ Edit the question of the duplicated filling it with a copy/paste  of the comment + Edit my answer + Request for re-opening… (Being lazy… I'd dislike this one)